# Pandas: Repeating list in column does not work

Tags: python, pandas

I want to turn a dataframe from this[image]

to this:

[image]

It took me a while to figure out the **melt and transpose** function to get to this

[image]

But I did not get to manage to apply the years from 1990 to 2019 in a repeating manner into for every of the 189 countries.

I tried:

```
 year_list = []
for year in range(1990, 2020,1):
    year_list.append(year)
years = pd.Series(year_list)
years
```

and then

```
df['year'] = years.repeat(30)
```

(I need to repeat it 30 times, because the frame consists of 5670 rows = 189 countries * 29 years)

I got this error message:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex on an axis with duplicate labels
```

Googling this error does not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be as follows:

**Sample data**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'country': ['Afghanistan','Angola']}

data.update({k: np.random.rand() for k in range(1990,1993)})

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

       country      1990      1991      1992
0  Afghanistan  0.103589  0.950523  0.323925
1       Angola  0.103589  0.950523  0.323925
```

**Code**

```
res = (df.set_index('country')
       .unstack()
       .sort_index(level=1)
       .reset_index(drop=False)
       .rename(columns={'country': 'geo', 
                        'level_0': 'time', 
                        0: 'hdi_human_development_index'})
       )

print(res)

   time          geo  hdi_human_development_index
0  1990  Afghanistan                     0.103589
1  1991  Afghanistan                     0.950523
2  1992  Afghanistan                     0.323925
3  1990       Angola                     0.103589
4  1991       Angola                     0.950523
5  1992       Angola                     0.323925
```

**Explanation**

- Use [`df.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.3/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) on column `country` and apply [`df.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) to add the years from the column names to the index.
- Now, we use [`df.sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) on `level=1` to get the countries in alphabetical order.
- Finally, we use [`df.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop` parameter set to `False` to get the index back as columns, and we chain [`df.rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) to customize the column names.

Comment: The usage of unstack does a lot for my understanding – because I used stack to solve my problem – where I should have used unstack. Many thanks!!